# Stripe checkout info does not save to Firestore Cloud Server

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

I am currently planning to implement a new Stripe checkout function on my Firebase web app. The link to the Stripe checkout is working, but for some reason when I tested a payment, the payment details does not save to Firestore Cloud for some reason. The Stripe webhook that is used by the project says that there is a HTTP 500 error despite the payment did work through the system.

The portions shown is the relevant code used for the project.

**/public/billing.js**

```
const checkoutButton = document.getElementById('pay-button')
const createStripeCheckout = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('createStripeCheckout')
const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_INSERT_STRIPE_PKEY')

checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  createStripeCheckout()
    .then(response => {
      const sessionId = response.data.id
      stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: sessionId })
    })
})
window.logout = function (){
    signOut(auth) 
    .then(function () {
        alert("Logout successfully!");  
        window.location.href = '/Login/index.html';
    })
    .catch(function (err){
        alert("Logout Error: " + err)
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

**/functions/index.js**

```
exports.stripeWebhook = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const stripe = require("stripe")(functions.config().stripe.token);
  let event;

  try {
    const whSec = functions.config().stripe.payments_webhook_secret;

    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
        req.rawBody,
        req.headers["stripe-signature"],
        whSec,
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("⚠️ Webhook signature verification failed.");
    return res.sendStatus(400);
  }

  const dataObject = event.data.object;

  await admin.firestore().collection("orders").doc().set({
    checkoutSessionId: dataObject.id,
    paymentStatus: dataObject.payment_status,
    shippingInfo: dataObject.shipping,
    amountTotal: dataObject.amount_total,
  });

  return res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP [500](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) indicates Internal Server Error, you need to check your server log to figure out why it's unable to process webhook events from Stripe.

Comment: Checked the logs, it says “Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value (found in field "shippingInfo").” on the logs.

Comment: Ok. So your code is trying to access a "shipping" field from a checkout session object, but it's not there.

Based on the API reference (https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object), a checkout session object doesn't have a field called "shipping", perhaps you are trying to get other shipping data such as "shipping_cost" or "shipping_details" ?

Comment: Yeah, that is the issue. Renamed the field to shipping_details and it worked now. Thanks for the help.